# How can I know the hostname of an Android phone for use in SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, android, hostname

When setting up public key authentication on SimpleSSHD server on my Android phone, by http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd/

> Quick start
>
> - Install SimpleSSHD.
> - On any computer which will connect to your Android device, set the port to 2222.  With OpenSSH, this can be done by putting these lines in ~/.ssh/config:
>
>   ```
>   Host myphone
>   Port 2222
>   ```
> - Launch SimpleSSHD, and in Settings enable "Start on Boot", then manually start it for the first time.
> - Create `authorized_keys` in the home directory (do not use `ssh-copy-id`)
> - Optionally make .profile

how can I find out the hostname `myphone` for my android phone?

My phone is assigned different IP addresses from time to time. For example, I can move my laptop and phone to different LANs, and my phone can reconnect to the same LAN.

Some attempts from my laptop:

First attempt (fail):

```
$ ssh -p 2222 192.168.1.87
user@C6730:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ hostname
sh: hostname: not found
```

Second attempt (fail):

```
user@C6730:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ ^D
Connection to 192.168.1.87 closed.
t@ocean:/home/t$ ssh -p 2222 C6730
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c6730: No address associated with hostname
```

Third attempt (succeed with some luck by guessing):

I find all the hosts in the LAN by  `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`, and guess which host in the output is most likely the phone. it is something like `android-c0f659b6548c28b2` (not the real host name)

- Will `android-c0f659b6548c28b2` change under some cases, for example, when the phone is restarted, moved to a different LAN, assigned a different IP address, ...?
- Does anyone know what `c0f659b6548c28b2` means? It is not the Mac address of the phone.
- Can I customize the hostname of the Android phone?

Thanks.

Comment: Your phone doesn't have a static hostname to which any IP address it gets assigned gets mapped.

Comment: Why is it? In comparison, how can my Lubuntu laptop have a hostname?

Comment: Note that I didn't say it didn't have a hostname.  I said it didn't have a hostname to which any IP address is assigned and mapped.  I can give my machine a hostname of 'bob', but it doesn't mean that I can log in from a remote node using 'bob'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [android.se].

Comment: @AndyDalton In fact, you can give your android phone a hostname (other than the one it asked for) just like any other system, if you control the dhcp server (eg. your router). On an OpenWrt system, this could be done with a `config host` entry in `/etc/dhcp`, on a custom dnsmasq-based system with a `dhcp-host` option, etc.

Comment: @mosvy In fact, I never claimed you couldn't.  If you control the DHCP server, sure, you can.  That's a special case, not a general solution.  The original question includes the condition of moving both the laptop and the phone to different LANs.

Comment: @muru Android is mobile operating system based on the Linux kernel, a modified BSD C library, and a Toybox BSD-licenced busybox-like multi-call binary. It makes hard use of some advanced Linux features, like SELinux and [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), which should be of interest to anybody working with Linux or Unix. As such, question related to android are __perfectly topical__ here, as long as they're not narrowly about googleplay / app issues or about programming its GUI.

Comment: @mosvy by your own answer, none of those seem involved (except selinux, and that only to the last question in the list), so by your arguments this off-topic.

Comment: @muru by your standard, awk,  jenkins,  bash, ssh, grep, text-processing, sed,  ...

Comment: @Tim are on-topic, since they're listed as on-topic. Take your pointless rhetoric elsewhere please, I'm not interested in having a conversation with you.

Comment: @muru Don't forget to do the same with your narratives please

Comment: @muru the Q is about where and how android (the most used Unix OS of all times) pulls that `android-febac7random` hostname and how it could be changed. It is of special interest to anybody trying to run eg. unix programs like ssh servers, or full fledged linux distros on android, and is, afaicg __not answered properly__ anywhere on SE: by closing it you're not doing real people searching for _actual info_ any favor, and are preventing them from giving better answers and from peer-reviewing mine, which makes improving it kind of pointless.

Answer (score 2):

> Will `android-c0f659b6548c28b2` change under some cases, for example, when the phone is restarted, moved to a different LAN, assigned a different IP address, ...?

It should only change when you factory-reset your phone (which may also happen as a side-effect of unlocking its bootloader).

From the command line, it could be queried by the `getprop net.hostname` command.

The string following `android-` is the [`ANDROID_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) from `Settings.Secure`, which is *randomly* generated when you first use your phone and is stored in the `/data` partition [1]:

- in older versions, in the `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` sqlite3 database.

- in newer versions, in the `/data/system/users/USERID/settings_secure.xml` file; notice that the `USERID` is not related to unix uids.

Even newer versions ([> 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#privacy-all)) make the `ANDROID_ID` unique to the device/user/app signing key combo and completely dispense with the `net.hostname`, which is no longer used by the dhcp client.

> Does anyone know what c0f659b6548c28b2 means? It is not the Mac address of the phone.

It should be random.

> Can I customize the hostname of the Android phone?

Not without rooting it [2], in which case `setprop net.hostname preferred_hostname` with the right privileges [3] should do it.

[1] Which is wiped clean on a factory-reset.

[2] Some devices have an option for that under "Settings / Developer options", but I wasn't able to find it on any of my devices.

[3] Newer versions of android drop capabilities and use SELinux extensively, so simply becoming root may be not be enough.